# implementing ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, listcellrenderer

I am stuck with implementing ListCellRenderer. This is my code.

I am getting the data from a DB in the form of Domain class that looks like this:

```
public class Domain {

    private Integer id;
    private String naziv;
    private Integer status;

    public Domain(){}

    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int i){id = i;}

    public String getNaziv(){return naziv;}
    public void setNaziv(String n){naziv = n;}

    public Integer getStatus(){return status;}
    public void setStatus(int s){status = s;}
}
```

Set up of JList:

```
        DefaultListSelectionModel m = new DefaultListSelectionModel();
        m.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        m.setLeadAnchorNotificationEnabled(false);
        DefaultListModel<String> modelRN = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 86, 390, 199);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        JList<String> listRN = new JList<String>(modelRN);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(listRN);
        listRN.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        listRN.setSelectionModel(m);
```

and this is how I populate the list:

```
        dRN = new DBdomain(s,a,b).Conn();
        for(int i=0;i<dRN.size();i++){
        modelRN.addElement(dRN.get(i).getNaziv());
```

where `dRN = ArrayList<Domain>`

So the problem is this. I am populating the list with strings that are Domain.getNaziv() but i want to change the background in the list where Domain.getStatus() has certain value. I know I need to implement something like this:

```
public class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
         @Override
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
             Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
             // do something
             return c;
         }
    }
```

The problem is that I am not populating Jlist with Domain but with a Domain filed which is a string, so the value argument in getListCellRendererComponent doesnt see the filed status so I don't know how I would mark the fields whose background I want to change.

hope I provided all the info and that somebody can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that I am not populating Jlist with Domain

Well DO populate `JList` with Domain.  Perhaps something like this:

```
public class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component cell = null;

        if (value instanceof Domain) {
            Domain domain = (Domain)value;
            int status = domain.getStatus();
            String naziv = domain.getNaziv();

            cell = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, 
                naziv, // note this...
                index, 
                isSelected, 
                cellHasFocus);

            if (status > 0) { // or whatever...
                cell.setBackground(STATUS_ON_COLOR);
            } else {
                cell.setBackground(STATUS_OFF_COLOR);
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: While I agree a data object should be passed as a model value, a renderer is not the right place to call `getNaziv()`.  Doing so breaks both accessibility and data transfer, which rely on the toString() of the model value.  The best approach is to either override Domain.toString() or wrap each Domain object in a class with an appropriate toString().

Comment: @whiskeyspider thanks . Could you help me out with that approach, not sure how to do it.@VGR

Comment: isn't it that when ever a JList renders itself it asks the ListModel for the elements it should display. so how to fill the Jlist with Domains??? I can kinda see what I need to do after, rendering every component with the value being naziv. @whiskeyspider

Comment: how to override Domain.toString() method so it works. thanks for all the input, really wanna make sense of this @VGR

Comment: @@whiskeyspider @VGR Ok so I got it working, I populated the model with Domains, and used the MyListCellRenderer you guys suggested, but know I messed up the isSelected colors somehow because the renderer is calling white(my else cell.setBackground(white)) as the color when i click on something in the list. Learned a lot but want to learn how to override the Domain.toString() as VGR said. thanks again

Comment: The toString() method body can simply be `return getNaziv();`.  Of course, if you plan to also display Domain objects in other components in other display formats, you will need to use a different approach.

Comment: @VGR thanks man, I though so but wanted to check with you. Can you please help me out with the added problem I have encountered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27063733/mouselistener-has-my-jlist-acting-strange . No one is giving any adivce, please check it out.