# mouseListener has my JList acting strange

Tags: java, jlist, mouselistener

I have JList that is loaded with Object has its ListCellRenderer and mouseListener, here is the code:

MyListCellRenderer:

```
public class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            Component cell = null;

            if (value instanceof Domain) {
                Domain domain = (Domain)value;
                int status = domain.getStatus();
                String naziv = domain.getNaziv();

                cell = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,naziv,index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

                if (status == 4 & !isSelected) { 
                    cell.setBackground( Color.red );
                    cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }

        return cell;
    }
  }
```

JList:

```
 DefaultListModel<Domain> modelRN = new DefaultListModel<Domain>();

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 86, 390, 199);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        JList<Domain> listRN = new JList<Domain>(modelRN);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(listRN);
        listRN.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        listRN.setSelectionModel(m);
        listRN.setCellRenderer( new MyListCellRenderer());
```

Domain class:

```
public class Domain {

    private Integer id;
    private String naziv;
    private Integer status;

    public Domain(){}

    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int i){id = i;}

    public String getNaziv(){return naziv;}
    public void setNaziv(String n){naziv = n;}

    public Integer getStatus(){return status;}
    public void setStatus(int s){status = s;}

    public String toString(){return naziv; }
}
```

That is the setup. What am I doing is getting data from a data base and loading it to a JList. The next step is the one when I click on a row in the list I want another Jlist to load corresponding filed from a data base.

Everything is working fine. I get the right values at my terminal but when I try to load the values to the other JList the first one that triggered the job is acting strange.What I mean by acting strange is the following. The list that has a mouseListener attached to it has 9 Domain elements in it(it only shows Domain.getName()). When I make a selection(one click) I get the right data in the second Jlist loaded, but the selection marker moves in the first one on its own. It moves one spot down, and it happens 9 times, and I don't have a clue why is that happening.

This is the listener code:

```
MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                 if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {
                      d = listRN.getSelectedValue();  //getting the object from the first list
                        System.out.println(d.getNaziv());
                  }
                 //RN-->>PL
                ArrayList<Domain>  x = new DBsearch(d).Conn();
                  modelPL.clear();
                 for(int i=0;i<x.size();i++){
                     modelPL.addElement(x.get(i));    //adding to second List
                     System.out.println(x.get(i).getNaziv());
                 }  
             }
         };

         listRN.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Does anyone have a clue to whats going on here? Thanks

Comment: can anyone help me with this problem???

Comment: I suspect it is related to `listRN.setSelectionModel(m);`.  Can you show the code that creates `m`?

Comment: @VGR thanks man. that was the problem. my listRN and listPL were both using the same SelectionModel(m) !!